# Netty ChannelGroup over ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, netty

I'm working on a multiplayer game server based on netty.
Most of the messages transmitted to the clients are specific to a single client
but sometimes i need to broadcast the same messages to all clients.

I'm not sure if there's a good reason to user a ChannelGroup over my own Map.
So right now i have:

```
public class GameSession {
  /* a map of all the players part of this game session */
  private ConcurrentHashMap<String, PlayerHandler> players = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, PlayerHandler>();
  private final ChannelGroup playersChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
```

Where PlayerHandler is:

```
public class PlayerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<IncomingMessage>
```

And contains stateful member variables.

When a new player joins (after going through some logic) he's being added to the GameSession:

```
public void addPlayer(PlayerHandler p) {

    if (p.getGameSessionID().equals(this.gameId)) {
        players.put(p.getPlayerID(), p); //add this player to our game session
        playersChannels.add(p.getChannelFromCtx()); //get channel and add to ChannelGroup
    }
}
```

Let's say i want to broadcast a message since a player requested to leave (or closed connection)

```
public void notifyPlayerLeft(String exPlayer) {
    //Broadcast message with the id of the player that left
    for (Map.Entry<String, PlayerHandler> entry : players.entrySet()) {
        PlayerHandler player = entry.getValue();
        player.sendPlayerLeft(exPlayer);

    }
}
```

Where sendPlayerLeft() is a simple method that does something like:

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(outgoingMsg)
```

If I use a **ChannelGroup** I can do something like this:

```
playersChannels.writeAndFlush(outgoingMsg, matcher)
```

but I'm not sure why that's a better idea. Netty states that it happens asynchronously
but since PlayerHandler does not have its own thread, wouldn't iterating over the objects 
like I did in NotifyPlayerLeft() will also be async? Please note that this entire scenario will be triggered by one Channel/User/Thread.

I hope that my questions are clear enough.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503586/writing-to-all-but-one-in-a-tcp-netty-channelgroup), Netty's default writing to a group is again a simple iteration. In that sense, there should not be a difference in performance and concurrency with your approach. The main difference is that it collects all futures into a Map, this grouping may help you track any problems raised. But why use your code if this is already implemented?

Comment: It's mostly a design choice. This allows me to generate new messages only in PlayerHandler and not in GameSession. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Updating it with information. So while the `ChannelGroup` is useful for the simple iterations as stated previously you also have this benefit taken from the API documents.

[Netty.io 4.1 ChannelGroup API Documents](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html)

> A closed Channel is automatically removed from the collection, so that you don't need to worry about the life cycle of the added Channel. A Channel can belong to more than one ChannelGroup.

You could go as far as creating a new `ChannelGroup.class` by extending the `DefaultChannelGroup.class` and add some methods to add additional behavior during the channel deregister to notify some code that a Channel is unregistered to then notify the other players, or do clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful with Netty's ConcurrentHashMap; it is actually buggy; it is not threadsafe. You can verify this bug with concurrent stream on one thread while putting on another thread. It is not always failing since it has to do with non-atomic internal array mutations (fast pace concurrent r/w should fail with netty's but not jdk's.)